# Apache poi-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar download link

Tags: apache-poi

Can somebody send me a direct link to download this file please: poi-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar? I am only seeing the .zip files on the internet and not the .jar files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to start at the [Apache POI Download page](http://poi.apache.org/download.html). From there, you'll see the link to download the *Binary Distribution*. Pick your preferred archive format (zip or tar), and follow the link to your nearest mirror. Download the resulting archive, and unpack.

Inside the binary distribution, you'll find all the POI jars, including their [dependencies](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components)